How to reconnect to rabbitmq via aio-pika
I have a producer:
class RabbitProducer:
    _CONNECTION: aio_pika.robust_connection.AbstractRobustConnection | None = None
    _CHANNEL: aio_pika.robust_channel.AbstractRobustChannel | None = None

    def __init__(
        self,
        login: str = config.SETTINGS.RABBIT.LOGIN,
        password: str = config.SETTINGS.RABBIT.PASSWORD,
        cluster_servers: str = config.SETTINGS.RABBIT.CLUSTER_SERVERS,
        heartbeat_interval: int = config.SETTINGS.RABBIT.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL,
    ):
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        self.heartbeat_interval = heartbeat_interval
        self.cluster_servers = cluster_servers.split(",")
        self.cluster_addresses = self._create_connection_addresses()


    def _create_connection_addresses(self):
        servers = [server.split(":") for server in self.cluster_servers]
        addresses =  [f'amqp://{self.login}:{self.password}@{server[0]}:{server[1]}/?heartbeat={self.heartbeat_interval}'
                   for server in servers]
        return addresses

    async def _on_connection_restore(self, *args) -> None:
        LOGGER.info(f"------ Connection restoring: {args} ------")

        self._CONNECTION = None
        self._CHANNEL = None
        await self.connect()

    async def _create_connection(self) -> None:
        if self._CONNECTION is None:
            for addr in itertools.cycle(self.cluster_addresses):
                try:
                    self._CONNECTION = await aio_pika.connect_robust(addr)
                    self._CONNECTION.close_callbacks.add(self._on_connection_restore)
                    break
                except aio_pika.exceptions.AMQPException as error:
                    LOGGER.warning(f"------ Rabbit producer connection error: {error} -----")
                    LOGGER.warning(f"------ trying to connect to the next node in the rabbitMQ cluster ------")
                    continue

    async def _create_channel(self) -> None:
        if self._CHANNEL is None:
            self._CHANNEL = await self._CONNECTION.channel()
            self._CHANNEL.close_callbacks.add(self._on_close_channel)

    async def connect(self) -> None:
        try:
            await self._create_connection()
            await self._create_channel()
        except aio_pika.exceptions.AMQPException as error:
            LOGGER.error(f"------ Rabbit producer connection error: {error} ------")
            await self.disconnect()

    async def publish(self, routing_key: str, message: dict) -> None:
        await self._CHANNEL.default_exchange.publish(
            routing_key=routing_key,
            message=aio_pika.Message(body=orjson.dumps(message)),
        )


RABBIT_PRODUCER = RabbitProducer()

I am unsure why when I disconnect the container with the rabbit node to which the producer is connected, my code does not go into _on_connection_restore()?
When I shutdown a container with a running node, I get this in the logs. I have a similar consumer in which I can handle a sudden stop of a rabbit node.
Unexpected connection close from remote "amqp://guest:******@localhost:56721/?heartbeat=10", Connection.Close(reply_code=320, reply_text="CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'")

NoneType: None

My consumer which processes the stop rabbitmq node in cluster:
class RabbitMQConsumer(consumer.AbstractConsumer):
    _CONNECTION: aio_pika.connection.AbstractConnection | None = None
    _CHANNEL: aio_pika.channel.AbstractChannel | None = None
    _QUEUE: aio_pika.queue.AbstractQueue | None = None
    _PROCESS_MESSAGE_CALLBACK = None

    def __init__(
        self,
        cluster_servers: str,
        login: str,
        password: str,
        queue_name: str,
        heartbeat_interval: int,
    ) -> None:
        self.cluster_servers = cluster_servers.split(",")
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        self.heartbeat_interval = heartbeat_interval
        self.queue_name = queue_name
        self.cluster_addresses = self._create_connection_addresses()

    def _create_connection_addresses(self):
        servers = [server.split(":") for server in self.cluster_servers]
        addresses =  [f'amqp://{self.login}:{self.password}@{server[0]}:{server[1]}/?heartbeat={self.heartbeat_interval}'
                   for server in servers]
        return addresses

    async def _on_connection_restore(self, *args) -> None:
        self._CHANNEL = None
        self._QUEUE = None
        self._CONNECTION = None

        await self._create_connection()
        await self.start()
        await self.consume(self._PROCESS_MESSAGE_CALLBACK)

    async def _on_close_channel(self, *args) -> None:
        await self._CHANNEL.reopen()

    async def _create_connection(self) -> None:
        if self._CONNECTION is None:
            for addr in itertools.cycle(self.cluster_addresses):
                try:
                    # self._CONNECTION = await aio_pika.connect_robust(addr)
                    self._CONNECTION = await aio_pika.connect(addr)
                    self._CONNECTION.close_callbacks.add(self._on_connection_restore)
                    break
                except aio_pika.exceptions.AMQPException as error:
                    LOGGER.warning(f"------ Rabbit producer connection error: {error} -----")
                    LOGGER.warning(f"------ trying to connect to the next node in the rabbitMQ cluster ------")
                    continue


    async def start(self) -> None:
        LOGGER.info("------ RabbitMQ consumer starting! ------")

        try:
            await self._create_connection()
            await self._create_channel()
            await self._create_queue()

            LOGGER.info("------ RabbitMQ consumer started! ------")
        except aio_pika.exceptions.AMQPException as error:
            LOGGER.error(f"------ Rabbit consumer connection error: {error} ------")
            await self.stop()


    @staticmethod
    def _wrap_message_callback(process_message_callback: typing.Callable) -> typing.Callable:
        async def _message_callback(message: aio_pika.IncomingMessage):
            async with message.process(requeue=True):
                game_match_event = schemas.GameMatchMessage(**orjson.loads(message.body))
                result = await process_message_callback(game_match_event)
                return result


        return _message_callback

    async def consume(
        self, process_message_callback: typing.Callable[[schemas.GameMatchMessage], typing.Any]
    ) -> None:
        self._PROCESS_MESSAGE_CALLBACK = process_message_callback
        message_callback = self._wrap_message_callback(self._PROCESS_MESSAGE_CALLBACK)
        await self._QUEUE.consume(message_callback)
        await asyncio.Future()```


I need my consumer to reconnect to the next running node if the one he was connected to before suddenly went offline


Were you able to solve this in the meantime?
